# Create columns from row with same ID

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a df like this:

```
Id      username  age

1       michael.     34
6.      Mike.          65
7.      Stephanie.  14
1.      Mikael.        34
6.      Mick.           65
```

As you can see, username are not writed the same for the same id. I would like to regroup all username to the same row like this:

```
Id      username      username_2    Age

1       michael.         mikael.           34
6.      Mike.             Mick.              65
7.      Stephanie.                           14
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` for count duplicated `Id` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then is possible reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last some data cleaning by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Id', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()])['username']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .add_prefix('username_')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    Id username_0 username_1
0  1.0    michael     Mikael
1  6.0       Mike       Mick
2  7.0  Stephanie
```

Or `rename` columns for start from `1`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Id', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()])['username']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .rename(columns = lambda x: f'username_{x+1}')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    Id username_1 username_2
0  1.0    michael     Mikael
1  6.0       Mike       Mick
2  7.0  Stephanie
```

Comment: Work fine! Do you now how i can't achieve this without deleting all others rows of my df?

Comment: @YoavTaieb - S there are multiple columns like `username` and need in output data same processing for them like for column `username` ?

Comment: Yes, but i also want to keep my previous data from my df. You see i have other columns that don't need this processing and i would like to keep them.

Comment: @YoavTaieb - Can you change data in question with expected output?

Comment: @YoavTaieb - So change `df.set_index(['Id', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()])['username']` to `df.set_index(['Id','age', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()])['username']` but need same values for each row like in data sample.